# How does the Angel generation work in the Steam Version of Adventure Capitalist?

Tags: steam, adventure-capitalist

I did a search around the internet about this, but [the wiki](http://adventure-capitalist.wikia.com/wiki/Angel_Investors) either refers to a totally different version of the game or is just plain wrong.

According to the possibly outdated wiki, you get Angels based on your lifetime earnings, which seems to be false since I always start getting Angels around my first few Billion and way faster than what is noted in the wiki.

So how does the Angel generation actually work in this version of the game?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/app/346900/discussions/0/618457398976349205/) in Steam Discussions, Angels are gained by lifetime earnings:

> *Q: How do you get angel investors?*
>
> A: Your Angel Investor total directly correlates to your all time cash earned. To receive the bonus from your angel investors, you must redeem them by performing a reset to gain angel investors.
>
> *Q: Is there a formula for earning angel investors?*
>
> A: [150 * the square root of (your all time cash earned in quadrillions)] – AI spent. This means that when you earn an angel investor, it takes more money for you to earn your next one.

Answer (score 1):

Angels generate depending on your total earnings **for the session** (since last reset).

Answer (score -2):

Angels generate based on how much money you make if all your businesses finished at the same time

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on this?